# Is it possible to show Elm's Debugger while using elm reactor?

Tags: debugging, elm

When using `elm reactor`, it works great but doesn't seem to provide a way to show the Debugger, to explicitly see the state of the model after each update.

`elm reactor --debug` doesn't work, I don't see an option in the UI, and didn't see it mentioned in [the documentation](https://guide.elm-lang.org/).

Can we see the debugger while using `elm reactor`?

---

Here's an example of code that runs in the Reactor but doesn't show the debugger (when using Elm 0.19)

```elm
module Main exposing (main)

import Browser
import Html exposing (Html, button, div, text)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick)


type alias Model =
    { count : Int }


initialModel : Model
initialModel =
    { count = 0 }


type Msg
    = Increment
    | Decrement


update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
    case msg of
        Increment ->
            { model | count = model.count + 1 }

        Decrement ->
            { model | count = model.count - 1 }


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ button [ onClick Increment ] [ text "+1" ]
        , div [] [ text <| String.fromInt model.count ]
        , button [ onClick Decrement ] [ text "-1" ]
        ]


main : Program () Model Msg
main =
    Browser.sandbox
        { init = initialModel
        , view = view
        , update = update
        }
```

Comment: What does your application look like? I typed in the introduction app from the docs and when running with reactor I see on the browser's bottom right corner the "explore history" option. When there are events/updates, those can be rolled back and forth. And which version of Elm are you using? Seems that I'm still running 0.18.0...

Comment: @kaskelotti Elm 0.19, and I've added a sample to the question.

Comment: In 0.18.0, the main function uses program from `Html` package. In 0.19.0 there's a separate `Browser` package with sandbox, application etc, i.e. it seems to have been re-implemented... Unfortunately my knowledge ends here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The debugger is no longer included by the `elm reactor` in 0.19. It was apparently removed while refactoring (although it will probably be re-added in the future).

For now, I'd recommend using [elm-live](https://github.com/wking-io/elm-live) which also supports auto-reloading.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there is no `elm reactor --debug` anymore. You will however still find a `--debug` on the regular `elm make`. So if your file was `src/Main.elm` you would now do:

```
$ elm make src/Main.html --debug
Success!

    Main ───> index.html
```

That `index.html` is generated with the `--debug` flag set. From `elm make`'s help, that means

```
--debug
    Turn on the time-travelling debugger. It allows you to rewind and replay
    events. The events can be imported/exported into a file, which makes for
    very precise bug reports!
```

So would've been really nice to have it in `elm reactor` but you still have an `index.html` that you can "open" in a browser. I put open in double quotes because if you open it by clicking on it, you won't see what you're expecting to see. You'd want to properly open it by — "serving" it from the terminal and then opening it's link on the browser, like you did with `elm reactor` . Most systems nowadays come with some version of python installed, so you can utilize a python command to do the "serving" of that `index.html` file with the command

```
$ python3 -m http.server 8000
```

If you only have python 2.x, that command should be:

```
$ python –m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

Of course, feel free to serve it any other way you want to. You could use `elm reactor` to serve that `index.html` as well. In the main window that `elm reactor` opens, locate the link to the generated `index.html` and click on it, instead of `src/Main.elm`. I'd advise against using this though, because it has the potential to be confusing. You might now be unsure whether you're looking at the main `src/Main.elm` file or the generated `index.html`.

As for `elm-live`, yes it's a great option, you can supply the `--debug` option as an *elm make option*.

```
$ elm-live src/Main.elm -- --debug
```

Pay heed to that `--` before the `--debug` option, as it marks the beginning of `elm-live`'s *elm make options* .

If nothing else, hope that clarifies where to find and use `--debug` still. Cheers.

*(Elm 0.19.1)*